# How can I view jquery success message after the form submit in php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to view a jquery success message after the form submit in php. I tried following code. But its not appearing. But when I code it in html it is working.But it is not after submiting. How can I achieve it?

here is my javascript code in php

```
    <?php
         if(isset($_POST['aaa']) and $_POST['aaa']=="Submit"){
    echo '<html>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
<!--
.container {width: 670px; margin: 10px auto;}
.messagebox {background-color: #F5F5F5;padding:5px;margin:10px 0px;border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;}
.errorbox {color:#000;background-color:#ffeded;padding:5px;margin:10px 0px;border:1px solid #f27c7c;}
.confirmbox {background-color:#F2FFDB;color:#151515;border:1px solid #9C6;margin:10px 0px;padding:5px;}
-->
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script >
<!--
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#messageBox").addClass("messagebox");setTimeout(function(){
$("#messageBox").fadeOut("slow")}, 4000);
});
function messagebox(){
$("#messageBox").removeClass().addClass("confirmbox").html("Item has been saved").fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(4000);
}
function alertbox(){
$("#messageBox").removeClass().addClass("errorbox").html("Oops, there was an error!").fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(4000);
}
-->

messagebox();
</script>
<body>
    <div class="messagebox" id="messageBox" style="display:none;"></div>
    </body>
    </html>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Well for one thing that will throw PHP parse errors - you have HTML directly after your `echo`, no closing PHP tag.

Comment: are you trying to do all that in the `if` loop in php?  I see the closing bracket is at the end

Answer (score 1):

Your code have some problems but to answer your question, You need to call your script with [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and in the callback function you show the message:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  data: data,
  success: function(message){
   //this will be called once the php has returned an answer
   $("#messageBox").removeClass().addClass("confirmbox").html(message).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(4000);
   }
})
```

**PHP**

```
//after processing the data, echo a response:
echo "Message has been saved";

//if an error occured, echo it
echo "an error occured";
```

**UPDATE:**

1. Don't output the entire page in PHP echo. just close the php tag and use regular HTML:

   ```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['aaa']) and $_POST['aaa']=="Submit"):?>

   <html>
     //regular html code goes here

   <?php endif;?>
   ```

   look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for more examples.
2. You don't have any button or form. What you should have is something like:

   ```
   <form action="myscript.php" method="post">
       <input name="email" type="text"/>
       //some more inputs
       <input value="Submit" type="submit"/>
    </form>
   ```
3. Now you can bind an event to the form submit and call the ajax:

   ```
   $('form').submit(function(){
   $.ajax({
     url: "test.php",
     data: $(this).serialize(),
     success: function(message){
              //this will be called once the php has returned an answer
     $("#messageBox")
       .removeClass()
       .addClass("confirmbox")
       .html(message) 
       .fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(4000);
      }
     })
    });
   ```

Sounds like you really need to learn some things about web development, i suggest you start [here](http://learncss.tutsplus.com/), and there are a lot of great resources on the web.